# Adding properties with a known type to an object doesn't carry over or preserve that type

Tags: typescript

I've got this situation I'm trying to puzzle around:

```js
type MyFooType = string[];
type MyBarType = (sound: string) => () => string;
type EntryType = () => (sound: string) => string;
type AnotherEntryType = Record<string, string>;


const foo: MyFooType = ['foos'];
const bar: MyBarType = (bleep: string) => () => bleep;

interface FoobarEntries {
 [key: string]: (EntryType | AnotherEntryType | any) // more than just these, I'd rather not list them all
}

interface FoobarType extends FoobarEntries, {} {
  foo: typeof foo;
  bar: ReturnType<typeof bar>;
}

const foobar: FoobarType = {}; // what to type this?

const init = (sound: string) => {
  foobar.foo = foo;
  foobar.bar = bar(sound);
  // and ~20 more
}

// app setup file
init('hello')

// used elsewhere in code
console.log(foobar.foo);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiB7RAVc0C8UDOwBOAlgHYDmA2gLoDcAUKJLCAEICGeaDWAFNogK5EAJgC4c%20YiQCUUDAD4oXaXLGFStetACiRfCA6YFS%20T35DRuVVJnyLE9eigBBIomAALCHm279MqACUIAGNEPEEAHltSABoVCVlaGhoQolwoADNkUTgkVAcsMgByTMRsQupkxFTgKAAjNmzmNl9uWoAbCAgwc3FSI0NrOo6uxOJgT3SWIOhc%20q8dQghsKABvGigyAGsIEB7LClEubzw9BwAfJxd3T2PThguWIhBpAHoXqABbUOh3R6gAKz4aWu2AgsRoAF8kmMJlMZsg5r4IAAPcZCZazNjHAhLVbrDJZKAaRDpAmIWhQOoNAIQYB8PBEfThYmkuYJSFJFJpEpzUSY9j5VYQqhQN5QADubhYNWAiCJDncBGwAH5OVU0sQCDVuLwBCI4n1BmtKTy2AA6Ep%20EoUslzM1zPxzEx6yS0KE0TXALiFDxtNqIQqSNWpRAdM3%20khcU14C3IV00IA)

I've simplified the problem, but I am not able to type `foobar` so that it preserves the types of `foo` and `bar` properties when I access it. In actuality, I have about 15-20 things on `foobar`;

But I'd need to make sure that the types of Foo and Bar are in `FoobarEntries` and either way I end up repeating the same data structure for foobar (list all the types in the type definition, then assign them inside `init`) once for types and once for the data itself

How can I get the types to carry across, or make sure typescript infers them correctly?

Comment: Either create a type for foobar or `const foobar : { foo : MyFooType, bar : MyBarType } = {} as { foo : MyFooType, bar : MyBarType }` Creating a Type will probably be prettier. Now you are just infering the type of foobar as Object.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 right, so I've started doing that, but the way I did it (see my edit) when I do and look at `foobar.foo` in other files the type it tells me that `foo` is is one of many types

Comment: Could you make the code into a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you're describing when we paste it into our own IDEs?  Right now there are a bunch of undeclared things that get in the way.  Also since `init()` is not being called anywhere, I'm not exactly sure where you want the compiler to know about the properties of `foobar`... could you show that?

Comment: @jcalz I'll definitely get to that, but I can't paste code across so you'll need to bear with me

Comment: @jcalz is that any clearer?

Comment: Maybe? (note that your code has at least one typo). Is there a reason you're doing it this way instead of just passing around `foobar` as a value? TypeScript doesn't model type mutation of closed-over variables, so the only way to express this your way is to redundantly write out the desired type of `foobar` and then lie to the compiler when you assign the invalid `{}` value to it. If you pass values around without mutation then you have something like [this approach](//tsplay.dev/wOLgyN) where the types just work naturally. Could you show why you have to do it your way instead?

Comment: @jcalz I'm not certain, but I think some parts of `foobar` are used *before* initialization. Then when those have loaded, more of the application can run before we get to bit that calls `init`.

Comment: Without a [mre] of what you're talking about I don't know what to suggest.  Do you want to see my previous suggestions written up as an answer, or do you want to [edit] the question to give more clarifying information? Or some third thing?